# Why am I unable to get response from my API in django rest framework via jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST framework to create an API. It is working fine with cURL.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u ratan:qazwsxedc123 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/grocery/subcategories/
```

However, when I try to use jQuery to populate a `div` in a HTML page it is not working, I am getting a 403 forbidden error.

This is my code.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/grocery/subcategories/?format=json",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    username: "ratan",
    password: "qazwsxedc123"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('ratan');
  },
});
```

I thought it can be because of CORS, so I have tried `django-cors-headers`, but it didn't help.

Comment: try adding ```contentType: "application/json",``` as it looks like you're trying to send a json object. But then again in your CURL you are sending them in a header.

Comment: This really isn't a Django question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The problem was in his JS, but it's good to know all the details for context. He could have misconfigured his DRF somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your username and password incorrectly when making the request. This is discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax).

Try this method instead.

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/grocery/subcategories/?format=json",
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("ratan:qazwsxedc123")
  },
  success: function (){
    console.log('ratan'); 
  }
});
```